# How can I group tuples inside a list that have a similar value of one item and then sort them based on another item?

Tags: python

first let me explain a bit further what I said in the question.

I have a list that contains coordinates of rectangles and a string like this:

```
list = [
       (x0, y0, x1, y1, 'string 1'),
       (x0, y0, x1, y1, 'string 2'),
       (x0, y0, x1, y1, 'string 3')
       ]
```

My goal is to sort them by ascending y1 and ascending x0

Right now I'm using this method to sort them:

```
from operator import itemgetter
list.sort(key=itemgetter(3, 0))
```

The thing is sometimes the y1 coordinates are similar to each other and they mess up the order in which the strings are meant to be read.

Here's a simple example of this:

Ordered list:

```
[
(859.0005493164062, 155.95175170898438, 942.1799926757812, 267.6641845703125, 'apple'), 
(797.2904663085938, 157.01016235351562, 824.2350463867188, 268.2728271484375, 'red'), 
(717.056640625, 157.71969604492188, 754.2953491210938, 269.064697265625, 'The'),
(162.12901306152344, 345.8944091796875, 210.24722290039062, 381.1226806640625, 'is'), 
(234.13601684570312, 346.3544006347656, 291.0986633300781, 381.9940185546875, 'trully'),
(313.343017578125, 347.2441101074219, 332.92852783203125, 382.7861328125, 'delicious'
]
```

If I join the strings the phrase would read 'apple red The is trully delicious', but its meant to read 'The red apple is trully delicious'.

I can't simply reverse the order, or sort by 'x0' first beceause it would interfere with the other tuples inside the list and mess up the sentences even more.

So I think i'm looking for a function that groups the tuples based on if the 'y1' are similar (I'm thinking doing an if 'y'/'y' ~= 1 then group but idk how to deal with more than two tuples doing that), then apply the sorting by 'x0', and finally append them to a new list.

Any help is appreciated!

Edit 1: tried implementing this function:

```
import math
def round_down(n):
    multiplier = 10
    return math.floor(n/multiplier)*multiplier
```

This manages to round the coordinates to the lowest tens but there are coordinates that mess up as well.

I've identified the prblem I think.

Here's some visual aid:
[image]
The red rectangles are the bounding boxes of each word. The green lines represent the 'y' coordinate and go up by 10 while descending in the page. The blue dot is (x0, y0) and the purple dot is (x1, y1)

The problem lies when the blue and purple dots end up in different sides of the green line. Because now if I round 'y1' of 'delicious' it goes to 180 and if I round 'y0' it goes to 170.

So now idk what to do honestly.

Maybe create a larger rectangle that contains words between two 'y1' values, sort those and then move to the next group?

Grouping by similar 'y1' values as I intended in the first place would work too as I'm not rounding any values.

I don't truly know how any of these options would work as I'm not that experienced in programming. So, again, any help is welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably get the desired result using a custom comparison in the sort where the values are considered equal when their difference is below a given threshold.

Python no longer has a comparison option in the sort function and uses a key generating function but you can work around that using a special class that will implement the approximated comparisons:

```
data = [
(859.0005493164062, 155.95175170898438, 942.1799926757812, 267.6641845703125, 'apple'), 
(797.2904663085938, 157.01016235351562, 824.2350463867188, 268.2728271484375, 'red'), 
(717.056640625, 157.71969604492188, 754.2953491210938, 269.064697265625, 'The'),
(162.12901306152344, 345.8944091796875, 210.24722290039062, 381.1226806640625, 'is'), 
(234.13601684570312, 346.3544006347656, 291.0986633300781, 381.9940185546875, 'trully'),
(313.343017578125, 347.2441101074219, 332.92852783203125, 382.7861328125, 'delicious')
]

class Approx:
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.value = value
    def __eq__(self,other):
        return abs(self.value-other.value)<2  # custom comparison
    def __lt__(self,other):
        if self == other: return False
        else: return self.value < other.value
        
sd = sorted(data,key=lambda d:(Approx(d[3]),d[0]))

print(*(d[-1] for d in sd))

The red apple is trully delicious
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I have a question about this. This line ( `return abs(self.value-other.value)<2` ) is what determines the amount of difference the values have in order to group them together? If so, can I change that '2' to make the difference larger or lower? I'm asking this cuz some words are still getting jumbled and I imagine it's because that difference isn't large enough.

Comment: I changed the '2' and it solved the issues. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

If you round it to the nearest "10", you get the result you want:

```
>>> [x[-1] for x in sorted(l, key = lambda x: (round(x[3], -1), round(x[0], -1)))]
['The', 'red', 'apple', 'is', 'trully', 'delicious']
```

###### Edit:

To always round *down*, use `math.floor`:

```
import math
>>> [x[-1] for x in sorted(l, key = lambda x: (math.floor(x[3]/10), math.floor(x[0]/10)))]
['The', 'red', 'apple', 'is', 'trully', 'delicious']
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! This almost does it. Some words still get jumbled cuz some coordinates in the same line end in numbers that separates the words. For example, 165 is rounded to 170 right? and 164 is rounded to 160. So now it sorts those two separetly. Is there a way to just round both of them to 160?

Comment: I didn't see this earlier but I've updated my post just about that function.

Comment: I was able to solve it using @alain-t 's method. Thank you for you help!